# What are possible reasons why root user receives "Permission denied" when trying to read or write files?

Tags: linux, rpm

I am trying to upgrade an application using an RPM package, but I receive the error:

`cpio: failure to open file, Permission denied`

The file it tries to open is located at `/etc/rc.d/init.d` where root has every permission for the directory, as well as the file itself. I have already tried checking if the file is immutable, SELinux is in permissive mode. I am out of ideas, so what are other reasons why root would not be allowed to access files?

Comment: Insufficient information. What is the output of `ls -la /etc/rc.d/init.d`? Of  `id`? What package?

Comment: perhaps the file that you are trying to open is not in /etc/rc.d/init.d